# Why doesn't this method call work from within a prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to write better javascript but I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I have two method calls that write to a text field. The first one works fine, but the second one doesn't. Why is the text field variable undefined going thorough a nested call? Any help would be appreciated:

```
(function () {
    var TestObj = function (logEl) {
        this.log = logEl;
    };

    TestObj.prototype = function () {
        var log1 = function (text) {
            this.log.val(text);
        };

        var log2 = function (text) {
            log1(text);
        }

        return {
            log1: log1,
            log2: log2
        };
    }();

    $(function () {
        var logEl = $("#log");
        var test = new TestObj(logEl);
        test.log1("This Works");
        test.log2("This Dosen't"); //this.log is undefined
    });
})()
```

Comment: This would work: `log1.call(this, text);` ... though `this.log1(text)` is more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dc5 and Hayes pointed out the value of `this` is the invoking object. It's the object that comes before the function:

```
somebutton.click();//this is somebutton
click();//nothing before click, window is assumed or throw exception in strict mode
myObject.doSomething();//this in doSomething is myObject
```

Since log1 is available through [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) it doesn't throw an exception immediately (log1 is undefined) but `this` in log1 function is window since log2 didn't provide an invoking object.

To set the invoking object you could change code to:

```
 log1.call(this,text);
```

I'm not a big fan of throwing everything including the kitchen sink in IIFE as it creates unneeded [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) for every method. You can wrap your application an an object literal instead and use IIFE where you actually need [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
var app ={
  testObj:function(...
```

log1 won't be available through closures in log2 but you can call it using `this`

```
 this.log1(text);
```

More on prototype, constructor functions, inheritance and the value of `this` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, log1 is being called without any context.  The value of `this` when being called from log2 will be the global object, not an instance of TestObj.

Try changing it to:

```
var log2 = function (text) {
    this.log1(text);
}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8KLC/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is related to not using `this` in `log2`:

```
var log2 = function (text) {
    this.log1(text);
}
```

A fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/y66YT/